# Google chrome dev tools says 404 error, but the file is present and can be clicked right in dev tools!

Tags: php, jquery

I've got this script installed on two sites. In my localhost site, it operates fine. However, on my 2nd test site, the script below is returning a 404 error (in Chrome's developer console) on the color.php file.

Although, I can then click on color.php in the console and it loads fine and echo's out the correct value I'm expecting. I'm at a loss for what's causing the 404, but its preventing the script from getting to the alert() in the doColor() function. Any ideas?

```
$('#my_theme').change
(
    function() 
    {
    $("#largePreview").hide();
    var myImage = $('#my_theme :selected').text();
    $('.selectedImage img').attr('src','<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/styles/'+myImage+'/screenshot.jpg');
    $('.selectedImage img').attr('title',myImage);
    $.get('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/color.php', {theme: myImage, spot: '1'}, function(data){doColor('#my_theme_header_color', data);});
    $.get('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/color.php', {theme: myImage, spot: '2'}, function(data){doColor('#my_theme_sidebar_color', data);});
    $.get('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/color.php', {theme: myImage, spot: '3'}, function(data){doColor('#my_theme_spot_color_alt', data);});
    $.get('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/color.php', {theme: myImage, spot: '4'}, function(data){doColor('#my_theme_spot_color_alt2', data);});
    }
);

function doColor(el, color)
    {
    alert('in function docolor');
    $(el).val(color).trigger('keyup');
    $(el).attr('value', color);
    $(el).val(color);
}
```

Contents of color.php is below...

```
<?php
require_once('../../../wp-blog-header.php');

$myTheme = $_REQUEST['theme'];
$spot = $_REQUEST['spot'];
$myThemeColor = $myTheme."_color".$spot;
$myColor = get_option($myThemeColor);
$file = "styles/".$myTheme."/template.ini";
if ($myColor == "") 
{
    if (file_exists($file) && is_readable($file))
    {
    $ini_array = parse_ini_file($file);
     if($spot == 1){$myColor = $ini_array['color1'];}
     if($spot == 2){$myColor = $ini_array['color2'];}
     if($spot == 3){$myColor = $ini_array['color3'];}
     if($spot == 4){$myColor = $ini_array['color4'];}
    }
    else
    {
     if($spot == 1){$myColor = get_option('cb2_theme_header_color');}
     if($spot == 2){$myColor = get_option('cb2_theme_sidebar_color');}
     if($spot == 3){$myColor = get_option('cb2_theme_spot_color_alt');}
     if($spot == 4){$myColor = get_option('cb2_theme_spot_color_alt2');}
    }
}
echo $myColor;
?>
```

Comment: Good grief do you seriously want to do four separate HTTP requests just to get colors for your page elements?

Comment: This is just an admin control panel function that might get accessed once a month, if that. No worries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your web server doesn't know about the file on the second test server.

Could be a permissions setting.

What platform and web server are you using?

Comment: Its a customer's site. I'm pretty sure its hostgator reseller account. Its running PHP version 5.2.9 and WordPress version 3.0.3

Comment: Check the ownership and permissions on the file that's giving you the 404.

Comment: Thanks John, what should the permissions be? I'm just reading the file values and sending those values back to the parent script.

Comment: John, I can copy/paste the URL to the file and it loads fine. However, I'm still getting a 404 from the javascript console, when its called via jQuery. Wouldn't this rule out permissions?